# Why must I use keyword static when they don't have to?

Tags: c#, methods, static

I've been trying simple experiments to learn C# methods. The below code simply calls playerSelection() which asks the user for a character and returns that character to Main(string[] args). Main prints that to the console.  With the below code I get the following error "An object reference is required from a non-static field."

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;


namespace SimpleFunction
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        char cplayerChoice = playerSelection();
            Console.WriteLine(cplayerChoice);
        }

        char playerSelection()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a Character");
            char cplayerChoice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            return cplayerChoice;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now if I add the word static like so:**

```
static char playerSelection()
```

**it compiles and works.** I do understand static versus non...abstractly.

### Ok, so here is where I'm confused and the question comes.

I'm learning C# from a book and in that book they go through the below example to illustrate using methods:

```
using System;

namespace GetinPaid
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            (new Program()).run();
        }

        void run()
        {
            double dailyRate = readDouble("Enter your daily rate:");
            int noOfDays = readInt("Enter the number of days: ");
            writeFee(calculateFee(dailyRate, noOfDays));
        }

        private void writeFee(double p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The consultant's fee is: {0}", p * 1.1);
        }

        private double calculateFee(double dailyRate, int noOfDays)
        {
            return dailyRate * noOfDays;
        }

        private int readInt(string p)
        {
            Console.Write(p);
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            return int.Parse(line);
        }

        private double readDouble(string p)
        {
            Console.Write(p);
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            return double.Parse(line);
        }
    }
}
```

### Question:

Why in their example can they call methods without using the keyword static but I have to use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In their example, they're creating an *instance* of `Program`, and calling a method on that instance:

```
(new Program()).run();
```

This is more cleanly written as:

```
Program program = new Program();
program.run();
```

From within those instance methods, you can call other instance methods because you're implicitly calling them on `this`.

As an aside, if that really is sample code from the book, I suggest you get a different book: there are some very questionable aspects of style there. In particular:

- Method names should be CamelCased; certainly for public methods but typically private too
- The author is inconsistent in whether `private` is explicit or implicit
- Method names which refer to types should usually use the CLR name rather than the C# name, e.g. `ReadInt32` instead of `readInt`. Again, it's not as important for private methods, but it's a bad habit to get into
- Using `double` for currency values is a *really bad idea*
- The parameter name of `p` gives no information (in various places, used for different meanings)
- For user input, you'd typically use `TryParse` rather than `Parse`, and check the return value then potentially reprompt on bad input

Comment: @Logarr: Do you mean the recent "C# 5.0 All-in-One for Dummies"?

Comment: I got the 4.0 version a while back to get my first taste of C#. Before that my only programming experience was a semester of VB.NET.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Be good to see if you would pen a book for C# Beginners :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - great news - ill keep an eye on Twitter/your blog for details of when it may be out - it would be the book I'd recommend to anyone starting off with C# - I know myself I have bad habits from being self taught coming from a C and C++ background.  Would you include much about MVC and the web end of C# (Not sure if you do much in that area of the language?)

Comment: @KOL: I won't be including *anything* on that side of things, no. It'll just be an introduction to the language and the core libraries, basically.